# Regular expression to remove space between numbers in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to remove spaces between numbers wherever they occur in a given string. I have tried using the following expression, which works under some but not all scenarios:

```
result = Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<=\d) (?=\d)", "");
```

I have tested it with the following inputs:

1. With `input = "1 500 000 frobs."`, result is `"1500000 frobs."` (correct).
2. With `input = "There are 1 500 000."`, result is `"There are 1 500 000."` (incorrect).

I can't figure out why it works in the first case, but not the second. What am I missing?

Comment: The last works also for me.

Comment: Perhaps you have non-breaking spaces in your input? Try this: `(?<=\d)\s(?=\d)`

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski that would also match carriage return/new line characters which I doubt is what OP wants. Tested [here](https://regex101.com/r/fQ9jP0/1) I don't think it's the regex so long as the **global** bit is turned on, which I'm guessing it is because it's the _last_ space that gets replaced. Not doing this global would replace only the _first_ instance (unless there's something funky in the rest of the code not posted)

Comment: The regular expression "/(\d\s+\d)/g" is enough..https://regex101.com/r/fZ4cZ1/2

Comment: In C#, you should be using \p{Zs} to match any space. So, I'd use `(?<=\d)\p{Zs}(?=\d)` regex pattern.

Comment: @funkwurm agreed about `\s` - `\h` would be better

Comment: I'm using it in an MS Word Add-In, and it seems that Word replaces spaces with non-breaking spaces between numbers, so that does seem to be where the problem lies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `\p{Zs}` space character class will make sure the regex matches all spaces. I'd suggest this code:

```
result = Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<=\d)\p{Zs}(?=\d)", "");
```